# Find the first two digits which their sum is equal to 10

Tags: c#

I have an array of integers `intx[]`:

```
int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

I need to find the first two digits which their  sum is equal to 10.

Here's the code:

```
Output should like (4 and 6).
Output should like (3 and 7).
Output should like (2 and 8).
Output should like (1 and 9).

public string Test()
{
    int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int i, j = intx.Length-1;
    string s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if ((intx[i] + intx[j - 1]) == 10)
        {
             s = (intx[i].ToString() + " and " + intx[j - 1].ToString());
        }
        j--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Is the array always be sorted?

Comment: How about 1,9 - 2,8 - 3,7 -....?!

Comment: first two closed number's

Comment: It sounds like you are asking us to do your homework... BTW why isn't 1 and 9 an option?

Comment: What is a closed number?

Comment: Move it to the programming stack exchange if this is a challenge / puzzle

Comment: public string Test()
        {
            int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            int i, j = intx.Length-1;
            string s = "";
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if ((intx[i] + intx[j - 1]) == 10)
                {
                    s = (intx[i].ToString() + " and " + intx[j - 1].ToString());
                }
                j--;
            }

            return s;
        }

Comment: ``for(int i=0; i<intx.Count; i++)
{
if(intx[i] + intx[i+1] > 10)
{
Console.WriteLine(intx[i].ToString() + " and " + intx[i].ToString());
return;
}
}``

Comment: i need dynamic solution for this,

Comment: but you should have gave it a try and posted the code you tried that is not a way

Comment: The problem appears to be that you never do anything with `s`, you just assign it and then ignore it, forget about returning `s`, add it to a list and return the list, or just write it straight to console if this is a console app

Comment: Fairly straightforward - `Dictionary<int, int> list = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            for (int id = 0; id < intx.Length; id++)
            {
                for (int id2 = id; id2 < intx.Length; id2++)
                {
                    if (intx[id] + intx[id2] == 10)
                        list.Add(intx[id], intx[id2]);
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var twoDigitsSumEquals10 = intx
    .SelectMany((i1, index) =>
        intx.Skip(index + 1)
            .Select(i2 => Tuple.Create(i1, i2)))
    .Where(t => t.Item1 + t.Item2 == 10);
```

`SelectMany` builds a cartesian product between all `int`s in the array and all `int`s in the array with a greater index than the first(to prevent repetition).

Test:

```
foreach (var x in twoDigitsSumEquals10)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", x));
```

Output:

```
(1, 9)
(2, 8)
(3, 7)
(4, 6)
```

or only the first with "and" between like  `(1 and 9)`:

```
var firstCombi = twoDigitsSumEquals10.First();
Console.Write("({0} and {1})", firstCombi.Item1, firstCombi.Item2);
```

**Update**: here's the *same* without LINQ:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < intx.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int ii = i + 1; ii < intx.Length; ii++)
    { 
       if(i + ii == 10)
           pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(i, ii));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do the brackets come from in your output? I was going to suggest you join with `" and "` which would give the OP's required output

Comment: need only First combination. not require all possibilities, i just provided just example. user may request 1st combination only. it might be sum of 10, or sum of 9, etc. need only first combination.

Comment: @user3391687: i don't understand, i've shown how to get the first combination only. If you don't want to read my whole answer search for `"or only the first"` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything with `s` you just re assign it. Try adding the results to a list and return the list

```
public List<string> Test()
{
    int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int j = intx.Length-1;
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if ((intx[i] + intx[j - 1]) == 10)
        {
             result.Add(intx[i].ToString() + " and " + intx[j--].ToString());
        }
    }
    return result;
} 


foreach(string s in Test())
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

---

To just return the first, then exit the loop early

```
public string Test()
{
    int[] intx = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int j = intx.Length-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if ((intx[i] + intx[j - 1]) == 10)
        {
             return (intx[i].ToString() + " and " + intx[j--].ToString());
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: need only First combination. not require all possibilities, i just provided just example. user may request 1st combination only. it might be sum of 10, or sum of 9, etc. need only first combination.